# Can someone please write the full opening of this prayer right before they start rig veda mandala 1 suktam 1. From the first om to the om they start

Tags: vedas, rig-veda

https://youtube.com/watch?v=lW5WByctPsw&feature=share7

Thank you very much i really would like this opening prayer

Comment: can you give the timestamp where it begins?